# How to use macros in a included file

Tags: flask, jinja2

view.jinja

```
{% extends "layout/defaultlayout.jinja" %}
{% include('details.jinja') %}
```

defaultlayout.jinja

```
{% import 'elements/macros.jinja' as html %}
```

But i am not able to use the macro **html** in details.jinja without reincluding it

Comment: Do not really remember if this applies to macros, but try `include('details.jinja') with context`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Daniel's answer didn't help me. I had to import the following way

```
{% from "post_entity.html" import show_post with context %}
```

Here `post_entity.html` was file containing macro with `show_post` method

And then used following way:

```
{{ show_post(post) }}
```

Here `post` is a dictionary sent to template from **flask** `render_template`.

And the `macro file` file looked something like this:

**post_entity.html**

```
{% macro show_post(post) %}
    {{ post.photo_url }}
    {{ post.caption }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Thanks, can't upvote more than once otherwise I would. It would be nice having someone pointing out why adding `with context` fixes it — and also why you should get an error omitting it...

Comment: This works without `with context` for me on `Jinja2==3.1.2`

Answer (score 18):

It looks, from your examples, as if you're trying to import `macros.jinja`, and use *that* as a macro called `html`.  It doesn't work like that.

Macros are defined within a jinja file, with names there.

macros.jinja:

```
{% macro dostuff(x,y,z) %}
    <a href="{{ x }}" title="{{y}}">{{z}}</a>
{% endmacro %}
```

and you can then import whole files with the import tag:

```
{% import "macros.jinja" as macros %}
```

so then, in your current namespace, you will have `macros`, which points to the macros.jinja file.  To use the `dostuff` macro, you have to call `macros.dostuff(...)`.

You need do define a macro called `html` inside macros.jinja, import macros.jinja as `macros`, and then call it with `macros.html(...)`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: UndefinedError: 'macros' is undefined

Comment: Quotes is a must: `import "macros.jinja" as macros`