# Jinja Map/Format Decimal Values

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm having trouble formatting a list of values in Jinja.

Current List:

`[0, 0.2608695652173913, 0]`

Needed List:

`[0, 26.08, 0]`

Code:

`[{{ record['result']|map(attribute='record')|join(', ') }}]`

What is the correct syntax to apply the `format` filter with something like `{0:0.2f}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
def FormatDecimal(value):
    return "{0:0.2f}".format(float(value))

jinja2.filters.FILTERS['FormatDecimal'] = FormatDecimal
```

Then use this in your template...

```
{{ SomeValue | FormatDecimal }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I want to define this as a macro for use within Flask templates, could I do so using this format? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20308242/3689902

Comment: Yes, you can include the filter in your macro.  {% macro dostuff(x,y,z) %}
    <a href="{{ x }}" title="{{y}}">{{z | FormatDecimal }}</a>
{% endmacro %}